# Google Sign in fails on iOS 13 GM

Tags: ios, firebase, google-signin, ios13

My app has a Sign in with Google button. When I try to sign in on iOS 13.0 GM GIDSignInDelegate didSignInForUser:WithError: returns this error:

```
Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (org.openid.appauth.general error -3.)"
```

I have no clue how to fix this issue. I'm using Google Sign In 5.0.0 as part of Firebase 6.8.1.

Comment: "org.openid.appauth.general error -3" actually means the flow was canceled: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/master/Source/OIDError.h#L103
However, this error is not being passed to the user, so that you can catch it properly...

Comment: @LukasWürzburger Actually that's what I'm seen on screen: the alert that asks the user to allow the app to use google com ("App Wants to Use google.com to Sign in") shows briefly and then it hides by itself and I get the error -3.

Comment: That is weird. Are you trying to present another view controller or something like that?

Comment: No, I'm just calling GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn(). If I put a breakpoint in didSignInForUser delegate, I can see the whole stacktrace from signIn through Google's Sign In framework, then into AppAuth methods and back to the delegate.

Comment: Did you also use GoogleSignIn 5 before iOS13? I think it's a bug in GoogleSignIn 5

Comment: This same code works fine on iOS 12, but I've not used version 5.0.0 in production code yet. I also suspect the reason may be in the Google's framework, but I expect to see more people complaining if that is the case.

Comment: I faced the same error. If you trigger Google sign on on iOS 12, then cancel it, the console shows the same error: `org.openid.appauth.general error -3`. And I got this error at the same time on iOS 13:

`Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x7feef180ee00>)`

So I think it's related to the presentation target view controller. Still investigating...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out! The `AppAuth-iOS`, which is a open-source dependency of `GoogleSignIn` SDK, has been updated from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 in August, including [this](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/pull/431) iOS 13 support. So you need to run `pod update GoogleSignIn` to update the `AppAuth` to 1.2.0. The `GoogleSignIn` SDK itself hasn't been updated since 5.0.0, so that got me confused.

Comment: As I said, I'm using Firebase 6.8.1 and AppAuth version there is 1.2.0. It's not working for me though.

Comment: If you have been using `GoogleSignIn 5.0.0(Firebase 6.8.1)` before Aug 16, The `Podfile.lock` file may still have `AppAuth` 1.1.0, until you run `pod update GoogleSignIn` or `pod update Firebase`. Just so you can double check.

Also `Firebase` just released `6.9.0`. Why don't you try to update it too?

Comment: But how about the binary 5.0.0 google publishes? They don't seem to contain the fixes either.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen GoogleSignIn 5.0.0 does not contain the fixes - but the AppAuth 1.2.0 does, which is one of it's dependency library.

Comment: Yeah, we rolled back to the previous version for now. Waiting for Google to publish a new update. Disappointing that Google didn't test iOS 13.

Answer (score 3):

> Following is the solution for successfully having the login
> view. Call the signin method after the ViewController's view is appeared,
> it will not be dismissed programatically. I have just implemented in
> IOS 13 and it works fine.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeDrive]
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
}
```

Comment: Rather than putting it in viewDidiAppear, you should call it in viewDidLoad with some delay (0.0) seconds.

Comment: I bet the given solution is sufficient and why to add more process by causing some delay!

Comment: It may be the case that viewDidAppear get called multiple times due to other interactions on the presented screen.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the Firebase 6.9.0 SDK zip and experienced this same issue. The README indicated that the bundled version of AppAuth was 1.2.0. I was able to resolve it by updating AppAuth to the master version.

Specifically, I *removed* the AppAuth framework included with Firebase, and instead build AppAuth using Carthage.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference when other users find this question:

Google fixed this issue in `GoogleSignIn` v5.0.1. When updating your app to iOS 13, you'll likely have to update the GoogleSignIn SDK as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebase 6.9.0 from Carthage, add github "openid/AppAuth-iOS" "master" to your Cartfile below any Firebase entries.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if wrong.

I thought this error would happen without targeting.

Support not only from 13, but also from 10.

Solution, but don't keep your pod version up to date.

4.4.0.

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '4.4.0'
```

It was all right for this version.

I anticipated the error. Less than

The new version may use some code generated by xcode11.3,
So new is OK, existing one may stop processing at 13