# Objective-C: Google SSO dialog disappears very quickly with iOS 13+

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-signin

I have added a google sign-in button and followed the official tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios), however, there is a strange behaviour where the data usage dialog appears and disappears very quickly although the Google Sign in class is a singleton so it should not be nullified by ARC.

I also tried to update the `pod` but no luck with that too.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that **Google sign in pod** depends on another **open-source pod** called [AppAuth-iOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) and this pod was the cause of this issue and they release an [update](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/pull/431) to address this issue, I did 2 things.

- The first one was removing Google sign in pod version and not forcing it to be statically bounded,
  changed from `pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0.0'` to this `pod 'GoogleSignIn'`.
- The second one was upgrading the [AppAuth-iOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) pod from `pod 'AppAuth', '~> 1.1.0'` to `pod 'AppAuth', '~> 1.2.0'` and my problem was solved.
  Thanks to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57906366/google-sign-in-fails-on-ios-13-gm) also and particularly this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070276/6927433) as it helped me to figure out how to solve mine.